# One way HTML binding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I used to go with `ng-bind` (or shorthand {{}}) for binding some text into a span.

```
<p>Preview: <span>formattedPrice(price)</span></p>
```

As you can see, I had a function call `formattedPrice` while binding. Now I realize I should be able to add some HTML into this span. I tried `ng-bind-html="formattedPrice(price)"` but that doesn't seem to cut it.

Is there a way I can do it without creating another scope variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your app loads the [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
```

And on the HTML (example):

```
<script src="<PATH_TO>/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Without this module Angular will not be able to correctly parse the HTML you want to render.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sEyHtJ5IbSo2lZhVW5wO?p=preview)**

Comment: That indeed was the problem. Would give a try to @johnny's answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a filter.

Like this:

```
<p>Preview: <span>{{price | formatted}}</span></p>
```

example filter:

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).filter('formatted', function() {
  return function(input) {
    //return your formatted price here
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be a silly question. But does that work for HTML as well? Lets say the formatted price has `<strike>$20</strike> $10`.

Comment: For that you need to do something like this

    <span ng-bind-html="price | formatted"></span>